# Is there a better way to format this timestamp to ISO8601?

Tags: java

I have a timestamp that looks like this: `2015-11-12T20:45:24+0000`. This is generated by someone else's script, which allegedly uses the UNIX `date` command (probably something along the lines of `date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z`).

**However**, according to Java's `DateTimeFormatter`, the closest `ISO 8601` format for this would be [`ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME), which looks like: `2015-11-12T20:45:24+00:00` (**notice the extra colon at the end**). If I pass in my version of the timestamp, the parser is unable to process it, but if I manually add in the colon then there are no issues.

My question is, *is there an easier, more reliable/robust way to handle these timestamps?* I'm getting timestamps which may or may not have that final colon delimiting minutes and seconds, and currently my code has this validation in it:

```
// We expect a colon at index length-3 (the colon delimits the hours:minutes of the timezone offset)
char colon = ':';
int expectedIndexOfColon = string.length() - 3;

// If that colon is not there, add it
if (string.lastIndexOf(colon) == expectedIndexOfColon) {
    return string;
} else {
    int substringIndex = string.length() - 2;
    return string.substring(0, substringIndex) + colon + string.substring(substringIndex);
}
```

This looks hacky, and I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to handle these two different formats. I know about Joda-Time, but their parser also rejects the colon-less timestamp (from what I've tried). Additionally, Joda-Time recommends using Java's `java.time` for Java 8 anyways (which I am).

Comment: Create two formats which meet your needs, one with and one without the `:`, try both and use the one which doesn't fail

Comment: @MadProgrammer what do you mean by creating two formats?

Comment: You can use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` to create you own patterns.  If the text can sometimes have a `:` and sometimes not, you can use two formatters to check the text and use the one which passes

Comment: For example, I could use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")` to parse `2015-11-12T20:45:24+0000` and `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz")` to parse `2015-11-12T20:45:24+00:00`.  Simply create both formatters, put them an array or `List`, iterate over them and attempt to parse the input text until either one is successful or all fail

Comment: As @MadProgrammer says - it's actually very common to have separate formatters for reading and writing. And not entirely uncommon to have multiple formatters for more robust parsing of input.

Comment: Thanks guys! That worked. @MadProgrammer if you put that into an answer I'll accept :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is expecting multiple different formats, you need to accommodate for these difference.

A common approach is to put your expected formats into some kind of array of `List` and iterate over this, finding the format that doesn't throw an exception

For example:

- `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")` is able to parse `2015-11-12T20:45:24+0000`
- `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz")` is able to parse `2015-11-12T20:45:24+00:00`

You could use something like...

```
public static LocalDateTime parse(String text, List<DateTimeFormatter> formats) {
    LocalDateTime ldt = null;
    for (DateTimeFormatter formatter : formats) {
        try {
            ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            // Maybe log the failure if you're interested
        }
    }
    return ldt;
}
```

Then you might use something like...

```
List<DateTimeFormatter> formats = new ArrayList<>(2);
formats.add(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
formats.add(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"));
System.out.println(parse("2015-11-12T20:45:24+0000", formats));
System.out.println(parse("2015-11-12T20:45:24+00:00", formats));
```

Which outputs...

```
2015-11-12T20:45:24
2015-11-12T20:45:24
```

Comment: Do you know why it's `z` and `Z` instead of `x` and `X`? I'm looking at [the patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) and `x` and `X` seem more intuitive...but they of course don't work when I use them

Comment: Also thanks for your answer...I think this is like the 3rd question you've helped me with over the last few years xD

Comment: To me, it's not very clear why `Z` or `z` would make a difference (or why `X` or `x` would fail), form what I can tell, `x` or `Z` should have worked for both formats, but it didn't in my testing :P

Comment: Fair enough...I might ask that as a separate question